# Refetching resources by onclick from resourceAreaHeaderContent (FullCalendar)

Tags: javascript, onclick, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I am using the `resourceAreaHeaderContent` callback to print some HTML to my `resourceArea`, including an icon which is supposed to start a function (by `onclick`) which does some operations on resource sorting, writes them to database and refetches them from the database in the end.

However, if this function is outside the `document.addEventListener`, I get `calendar.fullCalendar is not a function` and if the function is inside the `document.addEventListener` it can't be found, saying `Example is not defined`.

I think I am missing something about the scope here or the function call from `resourceAreaHeaderContent` is not correct. I have a codepen at https://codepen.io/craftydlx/pen/RwaqbvL and here is the code:

```
function Test(){
  console.log("entering test");
  console.log(calendar.id); //prints "calendar"
  //$('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchResources'); //"calendar.fullCalendar is not a function"
    //calendar.fullCalendar('refetchResources'); //"calendar.fullCalendar is not a function"
  calendar.refetchResources(); //"calendar.refetchResources is not a function"
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, { 
      resourceAreaHeaderContent: { html: 
        '<div class="d-flex flex-column align-items-start">' + 
          '<div class="p-2"><div class="resourceLabel align-middle">Ressource</div></div>' +
          '<div class="p-2"></div>' +
          '<div class="p-2"></div>' +
          '<div class="p-2">' +
            '<br><i class="material-icons sorter" onclick="Test()">[ Test() ]</i>' + '<br><br>' + 
            '<i class="material-icons sorter" onclick="Example()">[ Example() ]</i>' +
          '</div>' +
        '</div>'        
      },
    headerToolbar: {
      left: 'today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'resourceTimelineDay,resourceTimelineWeek'
    },
      slotLabelFormat: [
        { month: 'long', year: 'numeric' }, // top level of text
        { week: 'W' },
        { weekday: 'short', day: '2-digit' } // lower level of text
      ],
    initialView: 'resourceTimelineWeek',
    resources: 'https://fullcalendar.io/demo-resources.json',
    events: 'https://fullcalendar.io/demo-events.json?single-day&for-resource-timeline',
  });
  function Example(){   //"Example is not defined"
    //$('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchResources'); //calendar.fullCalendar is not a function
      calendar.fullCalendar('refetchResources'); //calendar.fullCalendar is not a function       
  }
  calendar.render();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`calendar.fullCalendar('refetchResources');` is old syntax from fullCalendar v3 or below.

It should be

```
calendar.refetchResources();
```

(as per https://fullcalendar.io/docs/refetchResources)

You did it right in the `Test()` (albeit it's out of scope) so not sure why you didn't copy that in the `Example()` function.

P.S. To make it in scope in the `Test()` function all you have to do is make `calendar` global too.

Comment: Thanks! I just tried every way of calling `refetchResources()` I could find, so there were different ways in the code. The solution for me was to make `calendar` global.